# Declare functions of Internal modules which are only partly loaded yet - typescript compiler error

Tags: typescript

I use an internal module ("AllianceModule") which is split over two files.
The first is loaded during page startup. The second is just loaded when needed.
I changed the load script procedure from creating a new HTMLScriptElement to using $.ajax to load the second script.
I did this so that I could use a callback method when loading the second part of the internal module. This callback loads a method (called "entryPoint") which is part of the second script.

Visual Studio compiles everything well, and the program works fine.
Running the ts-compiler from commandline

```
tsc References.ts --out main.js
```

where references.ts contains all Files needed during page startup gives an error:

C:\sources\TSProject\Onload.ts(137,126): error TS2094: The property 'entryPoint' does not exist on value of type 'typeof AllianceModule'.

"entryPoint" is an exported "static" function of the second module, and it is not called from the  inside of the first module.

I tried adding

```
declare function entryPoint(allianceId: number, _parent: JQuery): void;
```

to the internal module, but the compiler throws the same error. Creating an interface and defining a var of the interface-type did also not work (but I suspect that I did make an error trying it that way).

How can I declare the method, so that the error is not thrown anymore (aside from "casting" to any and then calling the method)?

Onload.ts:

```
function onLoadDoThis()
{
    //some code...
    $("#aButton").click(function () { Scripts.scriptsAdmin.loadAndRun(3, 3, './Alliances.js', true, () => {(AllianceModule).entryPoint(0,null); } ); });
    //more code
}
$(document).ready(onLoadDoThis);
```

The file AlliancesBase.ts contains

```
module AllianceModule {
    //a lot of code always needed and thus loaded during startup
}
```

And the file Alliances.ts contains

```
module AllianceModule {
    //some alliances stuff only needed when the user does some specific actions

    export function entryPoint(allianceId: number,_parent : JQuery) {

        if (allianceId) {
            console.log('EinzelAllianz');
            (new AllianceDetails(allianceId)).allianceDetails(_parent);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Alle Allianzen");
            runTemplate();
        }
    }
}
```

I am compiling the References.ts in which only references to OnLoad.ts and AlliancesBase.ts  are contained.

PS:

The first answer suggested putting the declare function inside of the module. This did not help, probably because I am calling the method from outside of the module (click event of a button). i created a forwarding method inside of AlliancesBase.ts directly after the declaration:

```
declare function entryPoint(allianceId: number, _parent: JQuery): void;
export function entryPoint2(allianceId: number, _parent: JQuery) {
    AllianceModule.entryPoint(allianceId, _parent);
}
```

This does also not help, because I keep to call entryPoint as an exported function - and this exported function is not known to the tsc compiler when compiling the References.ts file.

Comment: Maybe post some actual code? It's hard to guess what might be going wrong from the text description.

Comment: I added the actual code to the question

Answer (score 0):

```
declare function entryPoint(allianceId: number, _parent: JQuery): void;
```

Is that wrapped inside a module? If not, then it is declaring a global `entryPoint` function, not a method inside the AllianceModule. Wrap it in `module AllianceModule { ... }` where you declare it to do that.

Comment: Sorry, this does not work. If I declare the function this way, it is only visible from inside of the module. I need to access the method from the outside. I created a forwarding method inside of the module - this works and type checking is at least guaranteed. But this is no elegant solution... I will accept your answer when no better solution comes up